# Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script

Tags: php, namespaces

I get an error when I load the signing script. The error is as followed:

> Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lphoto/cms/php/class/db.php on line 1

I use the following scripts / pages

**signin.php**

```
<?php namespace scripts;
 // get the auth class and the db settings
require_once("class/auth.php");

use scripts\auth\auth as authClass;
```

**auth.php**

```
<?php namespace scripts\auth;

require_once 'db.php';

//use scripts\db\db as Database;

class auth extends Database
```

**db.php**

```
<?php namespace scripts\db;


/**
 * Author: Lennard Moll
 * Licence: GNU GPL 3
 * Last edited 18 July 2015
 */

require_once  'db_conf.php';

use scripts\db\db_config as conf;
```

**db_conf.php**

```
<?php 

namespace scripts\db;
```

I don't know where the problem is. Hope any of you know how to fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: First try putting the namespace command on its own line and not on the `<?php` line

Comment: doesn't change anything either

Comment: this may be Byte Order Mark, aka BOM - convert your files to "UTF-8 without BOM", and check if this works

Comment: Are you sure that the `<?php` line is the FIRST line in the script? So there can be no HTML code or anything above the `<?php namespace xxx` line

Comment: I was pretty sure yes. I just rewrite that line and then it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for whitespaces between the php tag and the namespace. Maybee these white space is not shown in your editor.

Comment: Looks like it I guess.  There was a whitespace at begin of the namespace. It looks weird to me that it would crash the script

Answer (score 0):

make sure there is no whitesapce or newline before php declaration, ie no space before `<?php`